# How to Implement gvNIX/Spring Roo Datatables Master-Detail?

Tags: spring-roo, gvnix

I have a simple use case where I have an Invoice table and an Items table.

An Invoice  can have many Items and an Item can be on many Invoices, therefore in my database I have an InvoiceItem table too (3 tables total, Invoice, Item and InvoiceItem).

I am using Spring Roo (version 1.3.2 with gvNIX addon (version 1.5). I am wondering if it is possible in the course of creating an Invoice, I can add InvoiceItems on the *same* page rather than then navigating to the create InvoiceItem page and filling that out separately?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Tumaini take a look to http://geo-gvnix.rhcloud.com/pets?page=1&size=10 I think it is the feature you are looking for.

@frnore gvNIX has this feature, gvNIX lets you to define any type of "master- detail" view patterns using the datatables component.

Tumaini, thanks to Curt Huffman (https://github.com/Cujo13) there is an alpha version of the documentation in english. Yo can download it from https://github.com/gvSIGAssociation/gvnix/issues/23, then read the section *"2.10 Step 8: Screen Patterns"* to learn how to implement the screen pattern you need.

Another sources of documentation are the quickstart applications that you can found at https://github.com/DISID/gvnix-samples/

May the Force be with you.

Comment: hello eruiz, I have looked at http://geo-gvnix.rhcloud.com/pets?page=1&size=10 but that is not what am looking for. I have 3 entitites, Invoice, Item and Invoice Item. An invoice can have many Items. gvNIX/Roo creates CRUD pages for `Invoice`, `Item` and `InvoiceItems` which means when I finish creating an Invoice, I have to navigate to the `InvoiceItem` `create.jspx` to add an `Item` to an `Invoice`. I am asking if it is possible when I am on the `Invoice` `create.jspx` it allows me to add `Items` on the _very_ _same_ _page_.I hope this is a bit clearer? frnores  answer is on the correct path

Comment: Ok, I see, so something like this http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/ could be useful for you. Just add the fields of the Invoice inside the form to submit all the data in only one request. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not implemented yet on gvNIX. I'll guide you about how to implement it but I can't give you the specific resolution.

To implement this, you must add some code on your file ~/webapp/WEB-INF/views/invoices/**create.jspx** to add a new InvoiceItem field on Invoice creation page.

Then you must push-in the method **InvoiceController.create** from **InvoiceController_Roo_Controller.aj** and edit it to handle the input from InvoiceItem field so that it will take the identifier from new Invoice record created and use it to create a new InvoiceItem record also.

Here is a sample project that implements an example of this functionality:
https://github.com/frnore/gvnix-sample-detail-creating

I hope be helpful.
Best regards.

Comment: Would it be possible to share some code which achieves this? Am still quite new to Spring and Roo, so a first example would really help me to continue the rest on my own. Thank you

Comment: I have written an example about how to create an InvoiceItem when creating an Invoice as you need. Note that I am only creating an InvoiceItem record each time I save a new Invoice, you must customize the code to allow select more than one Item. **I'll edit my answer above with a link to the sample project**. Please, accept my answer if it works. Regards.

Comment: Tumaini please, accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I promise I shall, I just have not yet had time to go through it yet but I will by end of today, and update the thread with any actions or comments necessary

Comment: I have tried to create your application using your `log.roo` file, but the resulting web application has errors :-(